# Base64 email subject not decoding correctly

Tags: perl, email, base64, email-headers

I'm trying to see why my **base64** email subject isn't decoding. I use this *Perl* code to create it:

```
use MIME::Base64;
use Encode;
$subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . encode_base64(encode("utf8", $subject), "") . "?=";
```

Which gives me:

```
=?UTF-8?B?w63DsyBEZW1hbmRlIGRlIHJlc2VydmF0aW9uIGR1IHd3dy5jaGFtYnJlc2Rob3Rlcy5vcmcgLSBSZXNlcnZhdGlvbiByZXF1ZXN0IGZyb20gd3d3LmNoYW1icmVzZGhvdGVzLm9yZyBbI10=?=
```

If I copy and paste:

```
w63DsyBEZW1hbmRlIGRlIHJlc2VydmF0aW9uIGR1IHd3dy5jaGFtYnJlc2Rob3Rlcy5vcmcgLSBSZXNlcnZhdGlvbiByZXF1ZXN0IGZyb20gd3d3LmNoYW1icmVzZGhvdGVzLm9yZyBbI10=
```

...into this site to decode it:

http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/base64.php

..then it comes out fine!

The full email header looks like:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w63DsyBEZW1hbmRlIGRlIHJlc2VydmF0aW9uIGR1IHd3dy5jaGFtYnJlc2Rob3Rlcy5vcmcgLSBSZXNlcnZhdGlvbiByZXF1ZXN0IGZyb20gd3d3LmNoYW1icmVzZGhvdGVzLm9yZyBbI10=?=
```

This is how it comes out in my email client:

[image]

...and this is how I see it when converting it via an online tool:

[image]

UPDATE: This is actually how **Email::MIME** is creating the email:

```
From: "Andy chambresdhotes.org" <test@foo.org>
To: andynewby@bar.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?PT9VVEYtOD9CP3c2M0RzeUJFWlcxaGJtUmxJR1JsSUhKbGMyVnlk?=
 =?UTF-8?B?bUYwYVc5dUlHUjFJSGQzZHk1amFHRnRZbkpsYzJSb2IzUmxjeTV2Y21jZ0xT?=
 =?UTF-8?B?QlNaWE5sY25aaGRHbHZiaUJ5WlhGMVpYTjBJR1p5YjIwZ2QzZDNMbU5vWVcx?=
 =?UTF-8?B?aWNtVnpaR2h2ZEdWekxtOXlaeUJiSTEwPT89?=
Date: Thu, 11 Jan 2018 14:46:05 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="15156819650.22DF651.1990"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
```

The full Perl code I used to make the header, is:

```
    my $email = Email::MIME->create(
      header_str => [
          From => $from,
          To => [ $to ],
          Subject => $subject,
      ],
      parts => \@parts,
      attributes => {
            encoding => 'base64', # this was the trick
            charset  => "UTF-8",
            content_type => "multipart/alternative",
            disposition  => "inline",
        }
  );
```

Comment: "It comes out fine", "I get the expected output". You don't seem to have explained what the problem is.

Comment: @DaveCross - I've added a couple of screenshots to try and explain better :)

Comment: Email::MIME obviously does not expect the encoded subject since it encodes it again. It is unclear how you set the header but `header_str_set` and in most cases `header` expects the unicode string and not the encoded string. See documentation.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - aahhhh thats the job! Changing the encoding to base64 in the "main" object did it: `attributes => { encoding => 'base64', charset  => "UTF-8", content_type => "multipart/alternative", disposition  => "inline" }`. Could you give an answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Email::MIME` with `header_str` and then you try to give the encoded subject, i.e. something like this:

```
my $mail = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        Subject => '=?UTF-8?B?w4PChHJnZXJsaWNoZSBHcsODwrzDg8KfZQ==?='
    ]
);
```

As [documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME#create) `header_str` expects the unencoded (i.e. unicode) string and will encode the string itself. This results in the double encoding you see. To cite from the documentation:

> The `header_str` parameter is a list of headers pairs to include in the message. The value for each pair is expected to be a text string **that will be MIME-encoded as needed**.

Correct use would instead provide the unencoded string like this:

```
my $mail = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        Subject => 'Ärgerliche Grüße'
    ]
);
```

Alternatively you could provide the encoded string by using `header`:

```
my $mail = Email::MIME->create(
    header => [
        Subject => '=?UTF-8?B?w4PChHJnZXJsaWNoZSBHcsODwrzDg8KfZQ==?='
    ]
);
```

To cite the documentation:

> A similar `header` parameter can be provided in addition to or instead of `header_str`. **Its values will be used verbatim**.